# How can I write an eclipse template that lists all the fields in a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-templates

Is there a way I can write a template to generate constructor copy method:

```
public MyClass(SomeOtherClassWithSameInterface i) {
 a = i.getA();
 b = i.getB();
}
```

Honestly, it doesn't have to be perfect.  For each field I just want to generate:

```
 ${field} = i.get${field}();
```

It Needs to do it for **every field**.  It would *nice* if it did the camel casing ;-)